# Behavior on logicals and character percentages

Tags: r, percentage

I used `scales` to format a vector into the `percentage` format and have been mostly successful at running logical operations on this, however, I noticed some interesting behavior above double digit percentages and I'm wondering if anyone can explain this so I can avoid these cases.

Example vector:

```
library(scales)
x <- c(.2,.4,.6,.8,1.2,2.0,2.5,5.1)
> percent(x)
[1] "20%"  "40%"  "60%"  "80%"  "120%" "200%" "250%" "510%"
percent(x) < percent(c(.5))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

As you can see, the values below 100% are correctly identified as less or not less than 50%. However this doesn't work for values between 100-499%.

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: The result of `percent` is a character, not a numeric object. So it's comparing the values lexicographically, not numerically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The help function `?percent` says: `Value: percent returns a character vector`. If you ask `percent(x) < percent(c(.5))` than you ask for *string comparison*, and the string `250%` is indeed smaller than the string `50%`, because **2** comes before **5** (lexicographical sorting)

Answer (score 5):

The `formattable` package allows you to do exactly what you want: have numbers printed as percentages but still be able to calculate with.

```
library(formattable)
x <- c(.2,.4,.6,.8,1.2,2.0,2.5,5.1)
percent(x)
#[1] 20.00%  40.00%  60.00%  80.00%  120.00% 200.00% 250.00% 510.00%
percent(x) < percent(c(.5))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Note that this is exactly the code from the question except `library(scales)` has been replaced by `library(formattable)`.

The [introductory vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/introduction.html) gives more examples, e.g.,

```
p <- percent(c(0.1, 0.02, 0.03, 0.12))
p
#[1] 10.00% 2.00%  3.00%  12.00%
p * 1.1
#[1] 11.00% 2.20%  3.30%  13.20%
p + 0.02
#[1] 12.00% 4.00%  5.00%  14.00%
p + percent(0.02)
#[1] 12.00% 4.00%  5.00%  14.00%
```

The print format can be controlled, e.g.,

```
percent(x, digits = 0L)
#[1] 20%  40%  60%  80%  120% 200% 250% 510%
percent(x, format = "d")
#[1]  20%  40%  60%  80% 120% 200% 250% 509%
```

Also characters can be converted:

```
p <- percent(c("15.5%", "25.12%", "73.5"))
p
#[1] 15.50%   25.12%   7350.00%
p / 10
#[1] 1.55%   2.51%   735.00%
```

---

**Edit:** As  [suggested by Alistaire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554206/behavior-on-logicals-and-character-percentages/44555943#comment76106291_44555943), the `units` package also accepts `%` among many other measurement units but I find its usage less convenient *for the particular purpose*:

```
library(units)
set_units(100*x, `%`)
Units: %
#[1]  20  40  60  80 120 200 250 510
set_units(100*x, `%`) < set_units(100*.5, `%`)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

p <- set_units(100*c(0.1, 0.02, 0.03, 0.12), `%`)
p
#Units: %
#[1] 10  2  3 12
p * 1.1
#Units: %
#[1] 11.0  2.2  3.3 13.2
p + 0.02
#Error in Ops.units(p, 0.02) : 
#  both operands of the expression should be "units" objects
p + set_units(100*0.02, `%`)
#Units: %
#[1] 12  4  5 14
```

Both packages, `formattable` and `units`, have their merits on their own but are heading in different directions.

Comment: The [units](https://edzer.github.io/units/) package is also useful for this sort of thing

Comment: @alistaire I've picked up your suggestion and edited my answer. But I find the `units` package less suitable for this particular question.